# I'm trying to upload an image but can't setState to be reader.result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader, setstate

I'm trying to read a file and then set the state of imgSrc to be `reader.result` but for some reasons when I console log imgSrc I get an empty string or null.

```
let [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState();
let showFileName = (e) => {
    let uploadButton = document.getElementById("confirmUploadBtn");
    imgFile = e.target.files[0];
    let image = document.getElementById("profileImage");
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        // imgSrc = reader.result;
        let result = reader.result;
        setImgSrc(result);
        console.log(imgSrc);
        image.innerHTML = `<img src=${imgSrc} width="300px" height="300px" style="border-radius: 50%;" />`;
        uploadButton.textContent = "Save Photo";
    }
    if (imgFile) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(imgFile);
    }
    console.log(imgSrc);
}
```

Comment: have you already added a `console.log(result)` before the `setImgSrc` to verify that the result is indeed valid?

Comment: Yes, the result is a very long string, I think it represents the image file.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues: you instrumentation is misleading, and you are not using the result as intended.

1. `imgSrc` may not change right away after setting it, only on the next go-around, i.e., when react re-runs the component function.
2. You are writing HTML but missing quotes around the dataurl. You can either do

   ```
   image.innerHTML = `<img src="${imgSrc}" width="300px" height="300px" style="border-radius: 50%;" />`;
   ```

   or better yet replace the content of the `profileImage` div with an image, whose `src` property is `imgSrc` directly. Then you don't need to modify the DOM directly (by setting innerHTML), which should generally be avoided in React. Something like:

   ```
   <div id="profileImage">
     <img src={srcImg} width="300px" height="300px" style={{borderRadius: "50%"}}/>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: I've figured out where does the issue come from but I don't know why and how to fix it.
The issue comes up when using set ImgSrc inside the showFileName function, because even when I set ImgSrc to be a static string it doesn't set imgSrc.
Shouldn't the component rerender every time the state changes?

Comment: Yes it does, and depending on how you created it it will at that point overwrite any changes you made to your DOM. So please give the second approach a try.